# How to keep Tizen device screen on during execution

Tags: linux, wakelock, tizen, efl

I'm preparing an app in EFL and also have access to the dbus interface.

I wanted to know what would I have to do to keep the screen from dimming or going off during execution?

This would be similar to obtaining wakelock in Android for keeping the screen awake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the EFL apps, you have to include the capi-system-power and deviced in your project build.

In your code,

```
#include <power.h>
#include <dd-display.h>
```

and finally

```
display_lock_state(LCD_NORMAL, GOTO_STATE_NOW, 0);
```

got me what I wanted.